# Return value of another attribute if needed attribute is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a `User` model which has `fullname` and `email` attributes.

I need to overwrite method `fullname` somehow so it will return value of `email` when `fullname` is nil or empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried it with ActiveRecord, but does this work?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # stuff and stuff ...

  def fullname
    super || email
  end
end
```

It depends how ActiveRecord mixes in those methods.

Answer (score 4):

To do what you want, you can quite easily override the default reader for `fullname` and do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def fullname
    # Because a blank string (ie, '') evaluates to true, we need
    # to check if the value is blank, rather than relying on a
    # nil/false value. If you only want to check for pure nil,
    # the following line wil also work:
    #
    # self[:fullname] || email
    self[:fullname].blank? ? email : self[:fullname]
  end
end
```